# comparing entire data upto 5 decimal places using numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal and error output as desire pattern?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, testing, comparison

I have a data frame as

```
ent_id  buy new_perc_buy    sell    new_perc_sell
123 0.116211962 0.116198415 0.496314325 0.496256466
124 0.007214061 0.00721322  0.153933545 0.1539156
125 0.003410283 0.003409886 0.499973272 0.499914987
126 0.231587543 0.231560545 0.699696021 0.699614452
127 0.056794334 0.056787713 0.235372057 0.235344618
128 0.130377754 0.130362555 0.187575903 0.187554036
129 0.998294858 0.99817848  0.917661563 0.917554585
130 0.208247701 0.208223424 0.575032323 0.574965287
```

now I have to match **buy** with **new_perc_buy** (upto 5 decimal places) similarly **sell** with **new_perc_sell** (upto 5 decimal places) with correspond to ent_id and if it does not meet the decided condition it fails

as I am using **numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal**

```
import numpy 
numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal(df_ss['rnk_perc_buy'],df_ss['new_perc_rnk_perc_buy'], decimal=5, err_msg='false', verbose=True)
```

I am getting this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in ()
1 import numpy
----> 2 numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal(df_ss['rnk_perc_buy'],df_ss['new_perc_rnk_perc_buy'], decimal=5, err_msg='false', verbose=True)
3 # df_ss.head(10)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing_private\utils.py in assert_almost_equal(actual, desired, decimal, err_msg, verbose)
588         # check that both are nan if any is a nan, and test for equality
589         # otherwise
--> 590         if not (gisfinite(desired) and gisfinite(actual)):
591             if gisnan(desired) or gisnan(actual):
592                 if not (gisnan(desired) and gisnan(actual)):

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **nonzero**(self)
1477     def **nonzero**(self):
1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. "
1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

also there any way by which I get error output like below

```
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 5 decimals for **ent_id 123**
 ACTUAL: 0.116211962
 DESIRED: 0.116198415
```

Comment: Please do not post your sample data as pic

Comment: It seems odd, are you feeding that line to an if statement? Try adding `.values` after each closing bracket

Comment: Passing values instead of series works. Another line that works is `allclose = np.allclose(a, b, rtol=0, atol=1e-5)`